# Remove url on top of screen in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, timber

I'm writing a Wordpress plugin. Now when I create my first admin page using the Timber plugin I'm always getting the url of the button on top of the screen. The only solution is to remove this line in the controller function:

```
$data['addUrl'] = menu_page_url('AddRoom');
```

How can I remove the url on the top of the admin page?

In the screenshot below you can see the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$data['addUrl'] = menu_page_url('AddRoom',false);
```

Comment: Tnx that did the job.